# WRONGTYPE Operation in StackExchangeRedis 6.0.1 with Redis 6.0.14

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I added the following key through the `redis-cli`:

```sh
redis.cache.windows.net:6379> set test hello
OK
```

Then, using `StackExchangeRedis` I'm trying to get the value:

```cs
await _cacheService.GetStringAsync("test");
```

where `_cacheService` is injected through `IDistributedCache`. I'm getting:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

The type is a string, `TYPE test` returns "string" in Redis.

Update:

If I set the key through the code, it works:

```cs
await _cacheService.SetStringAsync("test", "hello");
// now GetStringAsync works
```